# '(', ')', <column constraint> or comma expected, got 'INTEGER'

Tags: database, sqlite, kotlin

I am trying to write my first Kotlin app using SQLite and here is the problematic part:

override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {

```
    p0!!.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $CAR_TABLE(" +
            "$CAR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $CAR_NAME TEXT," +
            "$CAR_COLOR TEXT, $CAR_MODEL INTEGER)")
```

I am facing this error message:

'(', ')',  or comma expected, got 'INTEGER'

interestingly enough if I delete the last part like this:

override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {

```
    p0!!.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $CAR_TABLE(" +
            "$CAR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $CAR_NAME TEXT," +
            "$CAR_COLOR TEXT)")
```

there won't be any error messages. Could you help me with it please?

Android Studio "Bumblebee".
Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably there is a problem with the column name(s). Post their definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. indeed there was. there were 2 columns with two part names. As soon as I got rid of the space in the name (CAR MODEL -> CARMODEL) the problem went away. Although it seemed absurd but anyway, no more errors. yay